# Execute command from visual mode and return solution still in visual mode

Tags: vim

Assume you are in visual mode (hit `v` in normal mode), and now execute `:execute "/word"`. This will take you to the first "word" match. However, you will now be in normal mode instead of selecting everything in between the original visual selection. Is there a way to achieve this?

I also tried with `:call search("word")` instead of "execute"

I know I could simply hit `/word` from the visual mode; but this is intended to be done from a vimL function, so I would like to use `call` or `execute`, since I was told... it is a better approach.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it is a better approach

Execute could be convenient, because it allows using variable values and keynames, such as `<CR>`. But by all means it's not a universal tool.

So just do `/word` if appropriate. But if you really need it, you can execute stuff starting from the normal mode:

```
let l:word = 'some other text'
execute "normal! v/" . l:word . "\<CR>"
```